# Lookup element by URL

Tags: plugin-development, url, localization

I'm trying to get an element from it's URL.

For example, say we have a url of `http://craft.dev/blog/article1`. Is there a function I can call within a plugin and pass over `blog/article1` that will return a corresponding element, if one exists, for that specific URL? I'm sure there is a way to do this with the router, I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ElementsService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#getElementByUri-detail):

```
$entry = craft()->elements->getElementByUri( 'blog/article1' );
```

Comment: That was a whole lot easier then I expected. I was looking on the routing services, did not even think to look on the element service. Thank you!

Comment: No worries – it's often like that with Craft, no? :)